# How to "extend object" using __proto__ in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript

I have this which isn't working:

```
export function extendObject<
  T extends Object,
  X extends Object,
>(x: T, a: X): T & X {
  const p = { __proto__: x }
  Object.assign(p, a)
  return p
}
```

But I am getting this error on the `return p`:

```
Type '{ __proto__: T; }' is not assignable to type 'T & X'.
  Type '{ __proto__: T; }' is not assignable to type 'T'.
    '{ __proto__: T; }' is assignable to the constraint of type 'T', but 'T' could be instantiated with a different subtype of constraint 'Object'.ts(2322)
```

Originally it was just this JavaScript:

```
export function extendObject(x, a) {
  const p = { __proto__: x }
  Object.assign(p, a)
  return p
}
```

and I would use it like this:

```
const a = { foo: 'bar' }
const b = extendObject(a, { one: 2 })
assert(b.foo === 'bar')
assert(b.one === 2)
```

How can I properly type this in TypeScript to get it to compile? I would like to use `__proto__` as a performance optimization, but if it's not possible to use, how else would I accomplish a similar thing?

I tried this too but no go:

```
export function extendObject<
  T extends Object,
  X extends Object,
>(x: T, a: X): T & X {
  const p: T & X = {}
  Object.keys(x).forEach(key => (p[key] = x[key]))
  Object.keys(a).forEach(key => (p[key] = a[key]))
  // Object.assign(p, a)
  return p
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try using object destructuring?

```
export function extendObject<
  T extends Object,
  X extends Object,
>(x: T, a: X): T & X {
  const p = { ...x, ...a }
  return p
}
```

Please note that this is not a deep clone. Any references existing on `x` and `a` will be shallow copied.

Comment: How do you do a deep one?

Comment: You'll probably need to use some deep clone library  or function and typecast the result.